# Забирать из data определенный div для вставки

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Нужно взять из результата выполнения скрипта данные под дивом "comments" и вставить в див "comments" на другой страничке. Пытался с помощью find, не находит. Что не так?

```
posting.done(function( data )
    {
        /* Put the results in a div */
        var data1 = $(data).find("#comments");
        $( "#comments" ).html(data1);

    });
```

Значение data:

```
   <div id="comments">
    Супер комментарий
    </div>
```

Comment: покажите (добавьте в вопрос) значение `data`

Comment: `$().find` ищет среди подэлементов

Comment: добавил, там код длиннее, но в целом нас же интересует только div comments

Comment: То есть мне обернуть в еще один див?)

Comment: да. "Боись дупликатных id!" Виктор Драгунский